# AngularJs exec order

Tags: angularjs

This is my app structure right now:

**index.html**

```
<html ng-app="employeeApp">
    <body ng-controller="indexController as indexCtrl">
        <div ng-view>
                <div ng-init="indexCtrl.validateUser()"></div>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**indexController**

```
function indexController() {
   console.log('indexController');
}
```

**employeeController**

```
function employeeController() {
   console.log('employeeController');
}
```

If I look into my console the `employeeController` is fired first. Why is that?

--EDIT--

**Route file**

```
function routeModule($routeProvider)
{
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: '../views/login.html',
        controller: 'authenticationController',
        controllerAs: 'authenticationCtrl'
    })
    .when('/home', {
        templateUrl: '../views/index.html',
        controller: 'homeController',
        controllerAs: 'homeCtrl'
    })
    .when('/werknemer/:id', {
        templateUrl: '../views/employee/employee.html',
        controller: 'employeeController',
        controllerAs: 'employeeCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
}
})();
```

Comment: You need to provide more code. Where's route code and view code for `employeeController`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually code starts to executes in order that it's was wrote. I mean If `employeeController` placed above `indexController`, his code will be launched first.

But actually it's **no point to think about controller's load order**.
Really, you code should be work no matter which order controllers start to execute

In normal case one page (or `ng-view`'s view) should have only one controller at same time.

And in this case you can add init functions right inside controlers:

```
function myController($scope) {

   (function init() {
      console.log('myController');
   })();

}
```

Comment: Thankyou, but how could I fire the indexController with every request?

Comment: Why are you care about requests to controller? I want to understand. Usually controller should be load only once (until you reload the page)

Comment: You know, it's better to use controller only for "page"(or "view" if you use `ng-view`, but not for block of html-code) . If you need some especial from block of html code, you should wrap it as directive.